# Ruby: Using instance variables from other classes

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I have the following code:

```
class Person

 attr_reader :name, :balance
 def initialize(name, balance=0)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
    puts "Hi, #{name}. You have $#{balance}!"
 end
 end

class Bank

 attr_reader :bank_name
 def initialize(bank_name)
    @bank_name = bank_name
    puts "#{bank_name} bank was just created."
 end

 def open_account(name)
    puts "#{name}, thanks for opening an account at #{bank_name}!"
 end
 end

  chase = Bank.new("JP Morgan Chase")
  wells_fargo = Bank.new("Wells Fargo")
  me = Person.new("Shehzan", 500)
  friend1 = Person.new("John", 1000)
  chase.open_account(me)
  chase.open_account(friend1)
  wells_fargo.open_account(me)
  wells_fargo.open_account(friend1)
```

When I call `chase.open_account(me)` I get the result `Person:0x000001030854e0, thanks for opening an account at JP Morgan Chase!`. I seem to be getting the <kbd>unique_id</kbd> (?) and not the name I assigned to @name when I created `me = Person.new("Shehzan", 500),`. I've read a lot about class / instance variables and just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are passing an instance object assigned to the name variable. You have to do:

```
 def open_account(person)
    puts "#{person.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{bank_name}!"
 end
```

Or:

```
wells_fargo.open_account(friend1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing an instance of `Person`, not a string.

```
  chase.open_account(me)
```

You have to either pass `me.name` or modify `open_account` method to call `Person#name` like this

```
def open_account(person)
  puts "#{person.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{bank_name}!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You passing an object to the open_account method

You need to do

```
def open_account(person)
  puts "#{person.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{bank_name}!"
end
```